# Problem with objects in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get used to writing object oriented, but often I get a little stuck. I have this queries that I want to use to create arrays.

```
    $user1 = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username='$oc->user1'"));      
    $user2 = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username='$oc->user2'"));
    $user3 = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username='$oc->user3'"));
```

I can get the location of user1 by doing so: `$location = $user1->location`, but I want to create an array with all the locations to the users and I have tried this:

```
        for ($x = 0 ; $x < $users_total; $x++ ){

        $user = "user".($x + 1);            
        $user_location[$x] = $user->location ; //array med stedet alle brukerne befinner seg    

        }
```

This should call `$user1->location`, `$user2->location`, `$user3->location` to array[0] [1] and [3]. But instead I get

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Whats the problem? Can't I add numbers to the string like this `"user".($x + 1);` and call the location `$user->location`. Isn't that the same as `$user1->location`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `$$user->location`. See [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). (Much) better yet, use [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: +1 for arrays, variable variables are seldom a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need double dollar signs: try `$$user->location`. Otherwise, PHP thinks you're trying to do `"user1"->location`, which obviously isn't going to work.